# How to make Peer-to-peer teams call preferably video call to a teams user from an external application(kiosk) using Graph APIs?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, videocall, microsoft-teams-js

I am building a kiosk / virtual assistant application where I want to integrate teams meeting SDK and API to achieve the following use case.

In my application, I have a page where I listed out all agents available to go on a video call/ meeting.

All the agents have devices installed with team's client app.

A user simply checks the available agents from the listing page in the kiosk app and chooses an agent to call.

On the other end selected agent who has the client app opened will receive the meeting notification and join the meeting

How can achieve the above, a similar experience like starting a ‘teams video call’ with any contact from the teams client app using teams meeting sdk or Teams APIs?

Note: I already tried meetings API and scheduling dynamic meeting creation which we don't want. We want to use the call API efficiently to make direct video calls to agents

To solve my use-case I followed the documentation mentioned https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

1. Created an app in AZURE with a communication service
2. Gave all permission related to Communication services
3. Created a Microsoft Teams bot and deploy it to Teams application
4. Then call the APIs to the bot which initiates video call to the Agent

But I am not able to any response from initiating video call by using the teams call APIs.

Comment: Could you please verify that your kiosk application is making the API request correctly to initiate the video call? Additionally, you can test the Teams call APIs using the Microsoft Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: Have you checked whether the API request is being sent correctly or not?